# jQuery eq() loop

Tags: jquery, loops, increment

can you help me with this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("ul.fam:eq(0) li:eq(2)").addClass("redbold");    
});
```

In this code, is there a way to loop or increment the '0' value in -> $("ul.fam:eq(0) ?
Like making it 0,1,2,3,4,5 and so on... and stop the loop for example when it reaches '3'

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) (less than index) selector, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul.fam:lt(4) > li:nth-child(3)").addClass("redbold");    
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/nMSc5/).

This will be the same as selecting `:eq(0)` through `:eq(3)`.  There's also a [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector for the other way around...you can combine both or [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get a range.

Comment: @Hamish - I think he wanted the first index, could be wrong though...but yes use it wherever the index you're trying to select is :)

Comment: I want the '0' value in eq(0) to increment then stop when it reaches '3' ... there will be a loop. Is that possible?

Comment: @Eron - Why do you need to loop? This will select all the elements `0` through `3` (the first 4) in one selector... I updated the above to make it select the `<li>` elements you want, give it a go.

Comment: Yes this is it, just forget about the loop :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Loops are sometimes necessary, but buddy Nick Craver probably has the easier answer.  Anyway, this is exactly what you asked for.

```
$(function(){
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
     $("ul.fam:eq("+i+") li:eq(2)").addClass("redbold");    
    }
});
```