# incrementing eq() with jquery

Tags: jquery

Somewhat related to what what is being discussed here:
[jQuery eq() loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190331/jquery-eq-loop)

I have any number of elements that can be added to a page:

instead of doing this:

```
$('.taskName a:eq(1)').addClass('fixme');
$('.taskName a:eq(2)').addClass('fixme');
```

//can I programatically add more here as items get added instead of having to code 1,2,3,4 etc?

I would like to have a count done and have the number inside the eq() be incremented as a new element gets added.

I got around the other problems so I removed any code that is no longer needed for this question.

Comment: So, which `<a>` tags do you want to have the class added to?

Comment: in three cases if it's inside a div that has the title words"Role: Repeter_Manager" -or- an empty title

Comment: What's wrong with the `.each`?  Why do need `:eq()`?  I don't think I'm understanding the issue here.

Comment: the root cause of why I am going this route, in other words is I am dealing with elements that all have the same class but need different styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I get it, but I'll try :

```
$('a').filter(function() {
   return $(this).closest('.taskName').attr('title') == '' || 
          $(this).closest('.taskName').attr('title') == 'Role: Repeter_Manager';
}.addClass('fixme');
```

Adds the class to anchors inside elements with the matching titles ???

Comment: sorry about not including the html in this case but it would be more confusing since it's really rendered as a .js file and has some jstl core conditions in there to make the tree-view work (I had to shoe-horn this formatting as an afterthought) It was never concidered when it was first created.

Comment: You can use the `filter()` function to filter out anything really, just add `$(this).index() > 10` or something like `if ( !$(this).is(':first') )` etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly which elements need `.fixme` since you didn't post your html, but I'll assume it's all but the first and last elements.  In that case, this will do the job:

```
$('.taskName a').slice(1, -1).addClass('fixme');
```

[`.slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)